# Using Conditional Statement in SLD GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, style, sld

Is there any way to use the **conditional statement** in **SLD**? somehow using `if_then_else` like this Pseudocode:

```
if (10 =< variable =< 100) {
    then Multiply variable by 2
} else {
    then Multiply it by 4
}
```

Or if it is also possible to have a multiple `if_then_else`

```
if (10 =< variable =< 100) {
    then Multiply variable by 2
} if (100 < variable =< 200) {
    then Multiply it by 3
} else {
    then Multiply it by 4
}
```

**Example.sld**

```
<ogc:Filter>
    <ogc:Function name="if_then_else">
        <ogc:PropertyName>variable</ogc:PropertyName>
        <!-- check if the "variable" is between 10 and 1000 -->
        <ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
            <ogc:LowerBoundary>
                <ogc:Literal>10</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:LowerBoundary>
            <ogc:UpperBoundary>
                <ogc:Literal>100</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:UpperBoundary>
        </ogc:PropertyIsBetween>

        <!-- if it is between this range then multiply it by 2 -->
        <ogc:Mul>
            <ogc:PropertyName>variable</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>2</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:Mul>

        <!-- else multiply it by 4 -->
        <ogc:Mul>
            <ogc:PropertyName>variable</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>4</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:Mul>
    </ogc:Function>
</ogc:Filter>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use something like this:

```
<ogc:Mul>
    <ogc:PropertyName>variable</ogc:PropertyName>
    <ogc:Function name="if_then_else">
        <ogc:Function name="between">
            <ogc:PropertyName>variable</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>10</ogc:Literal>
            <ogc:Literal>100</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:Function>
        <ogc:Literal>2</ogc:Literal>
        <ogc:Literal>4</ogc:Literal>
    </ogc:Function>
</ogc:Mul>
```

If you need more if statement you can change

```
<ogc:Literal>4</ogc:Literal>
```

with new `if_then_else`

More information about functions in sld expressions can be found on http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/filter/function_reference.html

Comment: 5+ years later, and this is still far more informative than anything found in the docs found at the link you reference! There's nothing in there to make it clear that you can chain functions